# "European" to US screw nomenclature mapping (and reverse)

Tags: screws

My wife's company allowed moving her raising desk for working from home. Not sure how it happened, but we've lost the crews which fixate the table top to the metal frame it's standing on.

I consulted with the PDF assembly instructions and it says we need the `ST4.8x19 (wood screws)`. As far as I understand, it's a *self-tapping screw with 4.8mm ø and 19mm length, with thread pitch unspecified*.

Is there (ideally, an easy) way to figure out whether the US mass-produced screw variety has an equivalent replacement? Or should I just convert the metric diameter and length to the closest value(s) and use such screws instead?

[image]

Comment: They're not European - they're metric.  They're used in every country in the world.  In the case of the machine screws (squared off ends), they really go in for round numbers, (i.e.not 6.35-1.27 x 19) so that tends to make them incompatible with Imperial.  But metric machine screws are readily available even in shabby hardware stores.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Currently, I am not even looking into the machine screws (still have the original ones). As far as why I called them European, see explanation below. I know the DIMENSIONS are metric. The screws may or may not be commonly used across the world, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are metric sizes.

4.8mm is a mighty peculiar size - usually they go in for round numbers.  4.8mm is 0.19 inches.

ASME #10 screws are 0.19 inches diameter.

**These are #10 wood screws**.

19mm is 3/4".  So they are 3/4" long.

Any #10 x 3/4" wood screw should do the trick.

---

By the way, 3.5mm is 0.138" which is the diameter of ASME #6.

Comment: I know the *dimensions* are metric. The screws may or may not be typical for regions other than Europe, that's why I named them so. As @SolarMike suggested below, I did the translation. I agree the screw resembles the #10 indeed. However, the head's diameter on my original screw is significantly larger than the #10's one. And that is a problem. So everything you said is right except the "ANY #10 x 3/4" should do the trick". Still, thanks for looking into my question!

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko **#10 describes the thread diameter and that is all**. It says nothing about head size, shape or slotting.  Screws with a variety of head sizes and shapes can all be #10.  If you have *particular* head requirements, then you either hit the best hardware store in town (hint: it's NOT a brand name) and search every single slide-out tray in the store... or, get online on McMaster-Carr or Fastenal and search or inspect the tech data and drawings they provide.

Comment: Keep in mind in some cases you can use washers as a substitute for a broader head.